Ways to perform bitwise operations with symbols inside Assembly constants?
I am working on learning to write ARM firmware and am trying to create a Vector Table.  I am using the GNU toolchain.
I have assembly code like the following:
MY_VECTOR_TABLE:
  .long 0                        // SP Init
  .long SYMBOL_TO_HANDLER1 | +1l // Reset
  .long SYMBOL_TO_HANDLER2 & -2l // NMI
...

The problem is that the assembler complains about the operands '|' and '&':

Error: invalid operands (MY_SECTION_NAME and *ABS* sections) for `|'


Error: invalid operands (MY_SECTION_NAME and *ABS* sections) for `&'

This suggests to me that the assembler does not have a way for bitwise operations to be encoded into the relocatable object file, as the symbol addresses won't be known until link-time.  However, addition and subtraction do work.  Maybe there are ways to encode those operations.  I didn't dig that deep into the specifications and implementations yet.
Realistically, this isn't a show-stopper for my approach to creating a hard-coded Vector Table as I am working with Cortex-M4, Thumb instructions only, and therefore the addresses for the Thumb routines corresponding to the symbols all have bit[0] set anyway.  Anything that I want to disable, I can just put 0.
However, this did get me thinking.  How can bitwise operations be done against symbols in assembly constants?  Is it simply impossible with these tools?  Doing this at runtime is not possible because this will reside in memory mapped flash, not ram.
I suppose, if all else failed, hexedit the binary image before flashing.  The data structures are not that complex.  Put that manual step in the pre-release procedures.  :D

Generally you can't do this; addresses are link-time constants but not assemble-time constants, and there aren't relocation types for bitwise ops, only addition.  See How to do computations with addresses at compile/linking time? - you could write a tool the post-processes your image.  You could do SYMBOL_TO_HANDLER1 + 1 if you align the location of the label so the low bit was clear in the first place.  (2-byte alignment is actually guaranteed for ARM / Thumb.)

There might be some toolchain support for making an address a thumb address by setting the low bit specifically, maybe with .type metadata or something, not by manually using bitwise operators.  So it's possible someone who knows the details could post a better answer.

The toolchain should be able to set the LSB appropriately if you use .thumb_func

I'm using NASM for 8086 code but perhaps my approach could work on a GNU toolchain as well. That is, you cannot do bitwise operations, shifts, or divides with relocatable addresses. But you can calculate deltas within a single assembly module, if they stay in the same section. These deltas need no relocation, ie they are simply scalar values, so you can do all sorts of calculations on them. However, you need to somehow pre-calculate where a section is placed and then manually add in this adjustment (as another scalar) to obtain the equivalent of doing calculations on a relocatable address.

Does this answer your question? Invalid operands for binary AND (&)

@PeterCordes Correct.  If you mark a symbol corresponding to a funcion as .type <symbol>, %function, the linker will set the LSB correctly when relocating against the symbol.

Dang.  I was hoping there was some trick that I was unaware of to get around the ELF linking limitation.  It doesn't sound like there is.

@EchelonX-Ray The trick is to declare the correct symbol type.  Then you don't need to manually set or clear bits.

You should be able to do this, if the SYMBOL_TO_HANDLER1 is in the same section.  You can make a 'veneer' or 'shim' that will call the real SYMBOL_TO_HANDLER1.  It is an extra instruction.  But a statement that you are doing this to denote thumb functions would be helpful.  Somehow the question is tagged as thumb, but no text to help people.  There are various valuable suggestion on how to handle thumb in the other comments.

@artlessnoise "Realistically, this isn't a show-stopper for my approach to creating a hard-coded Vector Table as I am working with Cortex-M4, Thumb instructions only, and therefore the addresses for the Thumb routines corresponding to the symbols all have bit[0] set anyway."  I mentioned Thumb in the text right there.  I was just curious if people had better ideas.  Thanks for the information.
